# Is there a Seleniumbase function to get the Browser's log?

Tags: python, console.log, seleniumbase

I read the Seleniumbase Docs, but I couldn't find a function to return browser's console log to my python's program. Is there a function to do that?

There is a function in selenium to do this: driver.get_log(log_type)
but I didn't find it in seleniumbase

edit: I realized that I can use above code in seleniumbase too:
sb.driver.get_log(log_type)
there are two logtype: 'browser' & 'driver'
but there is new problem, this code only returns Warning and Severe messages from log. new question is: How can i return Info type messages?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

See the example test for interacting with console logs: ([test_console_logging.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_console_logging.py))

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class TestConsoleLogging(BaseCase):
    def test_console_logging(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
        self.wait_for_element_visible("h2")
        self.start_recording_console_logs()
        self.console_log_string("Hello World!")
        self.console_log_script('document.querySelector("h2").textContent')
        console_logs = [log[0] for log in self.get_recorded_console_logs()]
        self.assert_in("Hello World!", console_logs)
        self.assert_in("SeleniumBase", console_logs)
```